# Microsoft Word unable to recogonize the langauge of my document

Tags: microsoft-word

This is a new phenomenon.
[image]

My Microsoft Word automatically select Chinese lanuage even though the entire document was written in English. Thie creates a problem for me since I need to see how many words I have written. I have clicked try to force select English (US) but to no avail. It jumps right back to Chinese for some reason. Note that the document itself was sent to me by a friend, not created out of scratch. If I create a new document out of scratch, or even if I copy the content of his document to a new document, the problem disappears.
[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See my article on the MS website: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b

Comment: Please check your input language, make sure it is English.

Answer (score 0):

When loading a document, the grammar and spelling will be set to whatever your default language is, or what the language was set to when saving the document.

It is not changing until you actually work on the document, which is why it appears to not work.

Microsoft Word will start spell check after a sentence is entered and you press enter on it. It uses that moment to determine the language, but before that moment it may only do spell check using the default language unless the checkbox `automatically detect language` was disabled.

Given that this is something you just want to do for one document, the proper course of action would be to simply change the language by clicking on Chinese and setting it to English.

Keep in mind that the document is likely translated from Chinese to English because there is a weird linebreak going on where words are cut halfway and continue on to the next line, something that is illegal in English writing. This will also make 2 sections of a word count as 2, so your count would be off too. Spelling will find most of these, but might not find all of them. If although is broken into all and though, you would not catch it, and it changes the meaning completely.

So keep in mind to fully read the text, in this case, understand it, and then correct the words that are broken in two.

Answer (score -3):

Files > options >Language
[image]

Comment: -1 this is a crude solution that may work, but really is not the way to solve it. Its like saying to a locksmith: Sir, I have trouble opening my door. It gets stuck. Locksmith: I'll remove the door for you. Unless you have a special meaning with this solution, but in that case you need to elaborate why this is the right solution. Just an image doesn't cut it.